# Check if a UIViewController is in the middle of being animated onto the screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Can I see somehow from, say `UIViewController A`, if `UIViewController B` is in the middle of the animation of being presented on screen?

I know I can add code to `UIViewController B` (for example some boolean value used in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` or in the completion block of `presentViewController:animated:completion:`), but I also have `UIViewController C, D, E, F etc`. So I prefer to check this only in `UIViewController A` if possible.

Does anyone if this can be done and in case of 'yes, it can', how..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, how do you animate the view of your `UIViewController A`?

Comment: do you ask "how" you make a boolean value publicly readable ?

Comment: UIViewController A is not being animated onto the screen, UIViewController B is.

Comment: @A-Live No, I am actually looking for a solution where I don't have to use this mentioned boolean value

Answer (score 1):

`isMovingToParentViewController` will tell you this, as long as the parent-child relationships are set up. For a modal presentation `isBeingPresented`.

Comment: I have indeed seen the methods you mention, but these only return YES when called from inside the methods `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. So I cannot use them from outside the respective viewcontroller